# How do I get permission for exam materials?

Tags: conditionals, exam, ulem, ifthenelse

MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{ulem}

book = 1
phone = 0
photocopy = 1
internet = 0
tablet = 1

\begin{document}
Book, \xout{phone}, photocopy, \xout{internet}, tablet, \ldots\ free or open.
\end{document}
```

I would like to mention which materials students can use for the exam. If the material is 1, write the name of the material. I want it to write as `\xout` if the material is 0. I've added a picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand{\book}{1}
\newcommand{\phone}{0}
\newcommand{\photocopy}{1}
\newcommand{\internet}{0}
\newcommand{\tablet}{1}

\newcommand{\allowed}[2]{%
    \ifnum#1=1
        #2%
    \else%
        \xout{#2}%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\allowed{\book}{books}, \allowed{\phone}{phone}, \allowed{\photocopy}{photocopies}, \allowed{\internet}{internet}, \allowed{\tablet}{tablet}, \ldots\ free or open.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally I would not use such a notation for an exam but be on the safe site and explicitly write

- allowed items: ....
- forbidden items: ....

to avoid potential misunderstandings and legal problems.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll take it into consideration.